# Creating Database

Tags: views, 7, database

I want to create a student database in a Drupal website.
There will be a page containing a form (name, id, age, phone)in the website, where data will be entered and stored.
Later on the stored student list can be retrieved or perform some operations on the database like sending sms to all the students.

Please note that students are not the site users, some other user will enter all the details of the students.

I am a newbie to Drupal.. Please guide me on how to do that...

Thanks

Comment: there is already an `user` table in Drupal which stores the user information. If you need you can add more fields (name, id etc.) to it.  
Just create a user role student by visiting `http://yoursite/admin/people/permissions/roles`.

Comment: The students are not the user of the site.... my aim is just to store their information...and as far as I know user table has the details of users that login/use the site.... please correct me if  I am wrong

Comment: oh ok. I thought you needed users of type student. I suggest you edit your question to clearly mention that students will not be users and who will be the actual users. And yes users table contain login information of the users. Adding new fields would create new tables with respective names..

Comment: already edited .... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are requiring a front end to view the data stored I would highly recommend bui[lding a bunch of custom [views](http://drupal.org/project/views). You can then go further and install [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to allow actions to be performed on multiple rows (students). You have send mail as a default option but for sending a sms you will need to install the [sms framework](http://drupal.org/project/smsframework)

As for the containers, Drupal 7 has fields which can be attached to user profiles, if they get pretty advanced you can use the [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module which just gives you a little more control.

If you dont need the attachment to an actual user account you can create a content type "student" which will allow you to add custom fields in the same way you can with a profile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
but my doubt is that.... in my case students are not the site users, some other user will enter all the details of the students... so your approach is suitable in that case....

Comment: Yea i got a feeling that would be the case from your question which is not the typical case. Either way Drupal will support this well with a huge range of modules to extend your functionality.

Comment: so sir your suggested way is correct in my case also?... should I need to develop my custom module?

Comment: Might not need one, just use a content type and set up the fields / permission etc via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Make a content type for student. And using CCK add all the field i.e. name, age,etc..
For phone, CCK phone module will be helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the default Drupal registration form, make the student entries users, even though you don't want them to sign in or anything like that. Put up some profile fields ([I think this is the new Profile followup for D7, Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2)) in which you could store some additional information and let them be filled on the registration form. Then afterward you could even export the users to CSV ([Profile CSV](http://drupal.org/project/profile_csv)). This way you could have some more flexible data to be used to for example SMS them.

Please make sure you configure a good default "Authenticated user" role, this role should not be assigned to any administrative functions. Or even better, create a new role "student" and be sure to assign the role to those new entries.

Using users is (I think) the right way to go, since you can afterwards (for unforeseen future proposes) even let the users login and share content which only students should be obliged to.